# Laravel 5 - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, public, laravel-artisan

Here's my routes.php:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', 'StaticPagesController@index');
Route::get('about', 'StaticPagesController@about');
Route::get('contact', 'StaticPagesController@contact');
Route::get('signup', 'StaticPagesController@signup');
Route::get('login', 'StaticPagesController@login');

Route::post('login', 'LoginController@index');
```

i'm running my site locally via **php artisan serve**

```
d:\xampp\htdocs\some-website>php artisan serve
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/
```

everything works fine. i can access each page (about, contact, signup, login) with no errors.
however, when i use XAMPP, i can only visit the index page:

```
localhost/some-website/public
```

i get a **NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143** whenever i visit one of the following:

```
localhost/some-website/public/about
localhost/some-website/public/contact
localhost/some-website/public/signup
localhost/some-website/public/login
```

**EDIT:**
i tried editing my routes.php file to:

```
<?php
    Route::get('/', 'StaticPagesController@index');
    Route::get('/about', 'StaticPagesController@about');
    Route::get('/contact', 'StaticPagesController@contact');
    Route::get('/signup', 'StaticPagesController@signup');
    Route::get('/login', 'StaticPagesController@login');

    Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@index');
```

but no luck.

Comment: You should not be able to access these pages with public/ in the URLs. Can you access them without public/ ? Your explaination is not that clear..

Comment: have u tried Route::get('/about', 'StaticPagesController@about'); ?

Comment: @CDF forgive me if i got you wrong, but from what i understand with what you said, i tried removing "/public/" and it led me to "index of /some-website" with the site directory. it's only now that i encountered this problem.

Comment: As said by @Peyman.H, you should put a slash at the beginning of the path too. Can you post the content of your .htaccess or virtual host?

Comment: i tried what @Peyman.H said, but i still get the same error. here's my .htaccess: (http://puu.sh/k6xeP/cbe7003c15.txt)

Comment: what is some-website in your URL ? maybe that's a problem!

Comment: well, i intentionally used "some-website" to name my project due to  'confidential' reasons. i don't think it's the problem, and it's not hyphenated either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out my problem was with the project's folder name. i had it in CamelCase notation. changing it to lowercase got things sorted out.
shoutout to those who helped!